# Can not save a Point into EmbeddedDocument MongoDB Dlask Mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I'm using:
python: 3.4.2
MongoDB: 3.2
Flask: 0.10.1
MongoEngine: 0.10.6

I'm trying to save a point into a PointField using code below:

```
from mongoengine import StringField, PointField, \
                        EmbeddedDocument, Document, EmbeddedDocumentField


class Location(EmbeddedDocument):
    name = StringField()
    point = PointField()

    def __str__(self):
        self.name


class Person(Document):
    name = StringField()
    location = EmbeddedDocumentField(Location)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

On console try this:

```
>>> location = Location()
>>> location.name = "Arroz"
>>> location.point = {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [12,22]}
>>> person = Person()
>>> person.name = "Juan"
>>> person.location = location
>>> person.save()
```

But when I try to save() launch an except:

```
mongoengine.errors.OperationError: Could not save document (location object expected, location array not in correct format)
```

Any idea what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

```
{"type": "Point", "coordinates": [12,22]}
```

is how MongoEngine stores the data in the database. It does that so it know how to convert it to an object when you read the document. When you interact with the field, however, you only need to deal with the coordinates.

```
location.point = [12, 22]
```